# How to get associated object created using after_create callback in rails transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have method which is saving my session and event

```
def create_session
   new_session = NewSession.new
   new_session.transaction do
       new_session.name = 'Somename'
       ....
       new_session.save!
       event =  new_session.event        #returning nil why?
       puts event.new_session 
   end
end
```

My `NewSession` class

```
class NewSession < ActiveRecord::Base    
   has_one :event, :class_name => SessionEvent, :dependent => :delete
   after_create :create_event

   def create_event
       SessionEvent.create(:name => 'Eventname', :new_session => self)
   end 

end
```

Now How can I get associated object created using after_create callback in rails transaction

Comment: make sure that you have 'new_session_id' in your event stable

Comment: new session is surely saved but event is not saving although sql insert query shows the correct data but in transaction I am not able to get event object

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
class NewSession < ActiveRecord::Base    
   has_one :event
   after_create :create_event

   def create_event
     self.event.create(:name => 'Eventname')
   end 

end
```

But make sure that you have **'new_session_id'** in your events table, if not then add it to events table or define foreign_key in you association as:

```
 has_one :event, :foreign_key => "new_session"
```

and now use your own model code.

**EDIT**

Rather then save whole 'self' in event model you just save 'self.id' as:

```
def create_event
   Event.create(:name => 'Eventname', :new_session => self.id)
end
```

And define you assoication as I suggested above **has_one :event, :foreign_key => "new_session"**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think self.create will create another entry in new session table not in event table. Isn't it creating a non ending loop

Comment: still didn't get it right but assigning global variable like `$event = Event.create(:name => 'Eventname', :new_session => self)` and accessing in controller resolved my problem

Comment: This means your association is not working, you can access the event in your controller as: event = Event.last, it will also work but not a good way to do.

Comment: Could you show the schema of your event table, if it is possible.

Comment: Sorry but I have changed my `NewSession` model for more clearity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have 'new_session_id' in your events table, then

```
class NewSession < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_one :event
  after_create :create_event

  def create_event
     self.event.create(:name => 'Eventname')
  end 

end
```

Comment: getting `undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: here **self** means NewSession object, To create event you need make sure that first new_session object has created and add strong parameters in controller

Answer (score 0):

**after_create()**  -

Is called after Base.save on new objects that haven’t been saved yet (no record exists). Note that this callback is still wrapped in the transaction around save. For example, if you invoke an external indexer at this point it won’t see the changes in the database.

so I w'll suggest you to use **after_save** callback

Comment: But after save is called on event update as well but I want to create `SessionEvent` only if its a new record that is why I tried using after create